# how can i loop a blackjack answer input

Tags: html, loops, blackjack

I'm stuck on a blackjack assignment. I cant figure out how to let the user say hitMe Y/N as many times as they want. I have the dealer side down.

```
let card = 0;
let total = 0;
let hitMe = true;
let dealer = 0;

//1st card
hitMe = prompt("Current total: " + total, "Take a card? Y/N");
// (hitMe == "Y"){hitMe = true;}
//se {hitMe = false;}
if(hitMe){
card = dealer = Math.ceil(11*Math.random()) + Math.ceil(11*Math.random());
total += card;
}


//final total
dealer = Math.ceil(11*Math.random()) + Math.ceil(11*Math.random()); //dealer always takes 2 cards
alert("Your hand is worth " + total + ". Dealer got " + dealer + ".");
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use an if statement and a while loop, like so:

```
  let card = 0;
  let total = 0;
  let hitMe = true;
  let dealer = 0;

  hitMe = prompt("Current total: " + total, "Take a card? Y/N");

  if(hitMe == "Y"){
    while(hitMe == "Y"){
      card = dealer = Math.ceil(11*Math.random()) + Math.ceil(11*Math.random());
      total += card;
      hitMe = prompt("Current total: " + total, "Take a card? Y/N");
    }
  } else {
    dealer = Math.ceil(11*Math.random()) + Math.ceil(11*Math.random());
    alert("Your hand is worth " + total + ". Dealer got " + dealer + ".");
  }
```

If the user doesn't input a Y, the final total will display.